# How to make Cloudinary link show raw content in UTF-8 format?

Tags: encoding, cloudinary

I am uploading text file using Ruby. Here is the code

```
File.open("content.txt", 'w:UTF-8') { |file| file.write(@items_string) }
@cloudfile = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload("content.txt", use_filename: true, unique_filename: true, resource_type: 'raw')
```

I get the URL like this https://res.cloudinary.com/hozgi1gq4/raw/upload/v1635939227/838588_ex5mb0.txt

As you can see it shows in browser with wrong encoding. How to force this link to show up in browser in UTF-8 format?

Comment: Weird, your link to the `838588_ex5mb0.txt` opens in my browser [(Chrome)](https://superuser.com/questions/1160003/) _"normally"_. I can see some senseful Cyrillic (Russian?) text…

Comment: i would have been happy if it was Cyrilic. it is UTF-8 encoded in Cloudinary, but shows in browser in Win-51 format ( is it really Cyrillic in your Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary does not manipulate the asset if it's uploaded as raw.
Thanks.

Comment: but why it shows contents of the file in wrong format? as you can see from the code, I upload it in UTF-8 format, while the browsers shows it in Win-51 by default